# Accidently Moved Public_Html to a folder in CPANEL X

Tags: html, cpanel

I accidentally moved my public_html in a folder WD, now my public_html cant be moved to home but can be moved to any folder.

I am using cpanelx

Comment: call costumer care of ur hosting service provider.. they will be able to help you restore it back to original path..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have root access of your server then you can move your public_html directory /home directory otherwise you can not move it and yes, you need to contact your hosting support to restore that on original path.

Comment: can't i redirect it to public_html some how?